# Testcafe - useRole issue - need a cleaner way to login

Tags: testing, automation, e2e-testing, testcafe, user-roles

We use TestCafe to run end to end tests. We use "useRole" to log in to our application and there seems to be a problem with login as "useRole" caches information and in our test we cleanup our DB for cleaner data during which one of the keys change which is part of the token issued during login.

I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to log in using useRole so that we have the latest token and login does not fail?

Or please suggest a different strategy to login to the application.

Please help.

Comment: Do you clean up the DB after every `test` that is run?  Could you not clean the DB after each fixture?  You could then utilize the .beforeEach on the fixture.

Comment: We cleanup DB after every fixture.

Comment: Then, the `useRole` should be the appropriate approach to this...use the `beforeEach` on the fixture.  I believe that the `useRole` cache should be cleared between fixtures...

Answer (score 1):

[User Roles](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) is an abstraction that operates with cookie, localStorage and sessionStorage. When you call the `useRole` method, TestCafe initializes a Role if necessary (executes Role's authentication function) and switches cookie, local and session storages' state of a page. It allows extracting authentication logic into a single place and speeds up the test execution time.
So, Role doesn't operate with the database state. A good place to clean up the database state - [fixture.after](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#fixture-hooks) hook.